# Linux find command copy found files

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I have mounted an image and have used the find command to show all file types found on the image

```
~/mounted $ find . -type f -exec file {} \;
```

I know how to direct the output of the command to a .txt document but I cannot figure out how to copy the files I have found to another directory.

Comment: What do you mean? All files? Or only those of a given type? If so, which type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running the `file` utility use the same technique with `cp`

```
$ find . -type f -exec cp {} /destination/path \;
```